# Subset dataframe with daterangeInput before further subsetting without Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

This is my first time using stackoverflow to ask a question so I hope the following is clear enough:

I am making a Shiny app where I plot my data using Leaflet. The plot currently consists of three layers (type = a, type = b, type = a+b), which can be selected by using checkboxes and where I've also added slicers for selecting duration.

Right now, everything is working, but I want to add a DaterangeInput.

My dataframe consists of five variables (in its simplest form)
name / location / type / duration / date. The same name can have numerous observations as they are events and different observations for the same name can have either type = a or type = b.

For my currently functioning Shiny app, I subset my raw data by group_by(name) for type=a, type=b and type=a+b. This way I get three layers, which I can select by my checkboxgroup. The subsetted dataframes are subsequently used within a reactive function to act when the slider is used to change the amount of markers on my Leaflet map.

What I want to do now is subset my raw dataframe by using the daterangeInput before everything else. The reason for this is that the date is the only unique variable, which is why I want it as the first filter, but didn't realize up until I made a functioning Shiny app where I just wanted to add one little thing :P

Here is a simplified version of my code

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(Title),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      #slider for number of events
      sliderInput(inputId = "events",
                  label = "number:",
                  min = 1, max = 100,
                  value = c(1,100),
                  step = 1),

      #type a and/or b
      checkboxInput(inputId = "a",
                    label = "a",
                    value = TRUE),
      checkboxInput(inputId = "b",
                    label = "b",
                    value = TRUE),

      #Daterange for events to plot
      dateRangeInput(inputId = "date",
                     label = "from - until:",
                     start = 1-1-2018,
                     end = 31-12-2019,
                     min = 1-1-2018,
                     max = 31-12-2019,
                     format = "dd/mm/yyyy",
                     separator = " - "),
      ),

    #printing map
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput(outputId = "map", width = "100%", height = 900)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({

    #plot empty map
    empty_map <- leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(lng = 5.583541, lat = 52.577159, zoom = 8)
  })


  raw_date <- reactive({
    raw[raw$date >= input$date[1] & raw$date <= input$date[2],]
    raw
  })

#other filters
  #removing duplicate adresses
  reactive({
    rawdate <- raw_date()
    Name_unq <- rawdate[!duplicated(rawdate$Adres),]
    Name_unq <- Adr_tot_unq[order(Adr_tot_unq$Adres),]


  #determining information per event
    type_ab <- rawdate %>%
      group_by(Adres) %>%
      summarise(Total = sum(duration), mean = mean(duration)) %>%
      ungroup()

  #link adresses and location  
    type_ab <- data.frame(type_ab,Name_unq$Longitude,Name_unq$Latitude)
    names(type_ab)[7:8] <- c("Longitude", "Latitude")

  #determining which layer to plot
  observeEvent({input$a
    input$b},
    {if(input$a == TRUE & input$b == TRUE) {
      lpRemoveAll()
      lpAddTotal()
    } else if(input$a == FALSE & input$b == FALSE) {
      lpRemoveAll()
    }
    }
  )

 #define functions and type_ab-layer
  lpAddTotal <- function() {
    observe(
      leafletProxy(mapId = "map", data = type_ab_slider()) %>%
        clearMarkerClusters() %>%
        addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(),group = "Total")
    )
  }

 #define function lpRemove
  lpRemoveAll <- function() {
    leafletProxy(mapId = "map") %>%
      clearGroup("Total") 
    }

  #functions to link sliders to layers
  type_ab_slider <- reactive({
    type_ab[(type_ab$Aantal >= input$events[1] & type_ab$Aantal <= input$events[2]),]
  })

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Concluding remarks:
I want to subset my raw data by using the daterangeInput, after which I want to do further filtering on that subset.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
raw_date <- reactive({
  raw  <- subset(raw, date >= input$date[1] & date <= input$date[2])
  raw
  })
```

and:

```
reactive({
rawdate<-raw_date()
type_a <- rawdate[type == "a"]
type_a
})
```

you don't need an observer in the second part, reactive does what you're looking for. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Barron for your fast response!
I tried your tip, but the markers didn't respond to the daterangeInput
I added a simplified version of my code to the question where I also implemented your tip.

Comment: ah sorry, i think i misread your question! To update your markers based on the `dateRangeInput`, you need to you an `updateSliderInput` within an `observe`r:

Here is an example which pretty much does just that  (where the `input$val` is your `input$date`):

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/updateSliderInput.html